# altering Table Owner of multiple synonyms

Tags: oracle, alter, synonym

I have 848 `NONEDITIONABLE PUBLIC SYNONYM` that have the `TABLE_OWNER` as Dev.

I want help to alter all these `NONEDITIONABLE PUBLIC SYNONYM` to Prod, but in order to do so we need to extract all the queries. Is there a query to do so?

current:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PUBLIC SYNONYM "CONFIG_SEQ" FOR "Dev"."CONFIG_SEQ";
```

expected:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PUBLIC SYNONYM "CONFIG_SEQ" FOR "Prod"."CONFIG_SEQ";
```

your time and help is appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: but in order to do so we need to extract all the queries. Is there a query to do so?

Answer (score 2):

> we need to extract all the queries. Is there a query to do so?

Yes. Generate the script from the data dictionary:

```
select 'CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PUBLIC SYNONYM "'
       || synonym_name ||'" FOR "PROD"."' || table_name || '";'
from all_synonyms
where owner = 'PUBLIC'
and   table_owner = 'DEV'
/
```

For future reference please remember that needing to do this is **a failure of process**. DDL scripts are just like any other code, and should be kept in a source control repository, and checked out and deployed through managed releases.